# Using HTML5 canvas tutorial. Menu not working. Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

For some reason my code for the drawing portion of this HTML5 canvas tutorial is working quite fine. But I can't get the menu to show up.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="tools">
  <a href="#colors_sketch" data-download="png" style="float: right; width: 100px;">Download</a>
</div>
    <canvas id="simple_sketch" width="1200" height="800"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
  });

  $(function() {
    $.each(['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0', '#0ff', '#00f', '#f0f', '#000', '#fff'], function() {
      $('#colors_demo .tools').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-color='" + this + "' style='width: 10px; background: " + this + ";'></a> ");
    });
    $.each([3, 5, 10, 15], function() {
      $('#colors_demo .tools').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-size='" + this + "' style='background: #ccc'>" + this + "</a> ");
    });
    $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: are you missing some code? I don't see tags matching any of your selectors other than #colors_sketch and #simple_sketch.

Comment: No, the drawing portion actually works quite fine

Comment: Completely sorry, I thought I had written that I was using the Sketch.js plugin